# not getting ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.I am trying to get a newly changed value from a input tag using ng-model but it is returning me the previous value.Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?
{{eventDateControl}} is the model.

```
<div ng-controller="EventInfoController">

<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveEventInfo(eventData,alertType,eventDateControl)">

        <div class="form-group bottom-border-field">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Event Date & Time:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-12"
                    data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z"                        
                    data-date-format="MM dd, yyyy,HH:mm p"
                    data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input id="currentDate" class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" ng-model="eventDateControl" readonly>
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                     </span>
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                     </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

controller

```
alertCallApp.controller('EventInfoController',
function($q, $scope,$rootScope,$timeout,$http,eventDetails,$stateParams,currentEventID,getUserDetails,alertAppLib,currentEventStatus,alertTypeDetails) {


$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    // language: 'fr',
    weekStart : 1,
    todayBtn : 1,
    autoclose : 1,
    todayHighlight : 1,
    startView : 2,
    forceParse : 0,
    showMeridian : 1
});

$scope.getEventDetails = function(){


            //  get updateTime in millisec and format in proper format

            var udate = eventResponse.data.alertEvent.updateTime;
            var cdate = eventResponse.data.alertEvent.createTime;

            //  converting updateTime in proper format
            var d = new Date(udate);

            var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

            var date = d.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' '+ (d.getYear() + 1900) + '-' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes()
            var ampm = (d.getHours() >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";

            console.log('updateTime in expected format : '+ date+' '+ampm);

            $scope.eventDateControl = date+' '+ampm;

            //  converting createTime in proper format
            d = new Date(cdate);

            monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

            date = d.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' '+ (d.getYear() + 1900) + '-' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes()
            ampm = (d.getHours() >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";

            console.log('createTime in expected format : '+ date+' '+ampm);

            $scope.createTime = date+' '+ampm;

        } else {
            errMsg = eventResponse.statusMessage;
        }
    });
}



$scope.saveEventInfo = function(eventData,alertType,eventDateControl){

    console.log('eventDateControl :  '+eventDateControl);

    //GET DATE AND CHANGE IT TO MILLISECONDS

        //  converting createTime in proper format

    var res = eventDateControl.split(" ");
    var day = res[0];
    var month = res[1];
    var year = res[2];
    var hours = res[3];

    var res1 = res[2].split("-");
    var year = res1[0];
    var hm = res1[1].split(":");
    var hours = hm[0];
    var min = hm[1];

    var date = new Date(''+year+','+month+','+day+','+hours+':'+min);

    console.log('selected updateTime in ms: '+date.getTime());
```

}

fetching the new value here

```
 $scope.saveEventInfo = function(eventData,alertType,eventDateControl){

//CHANGED DATE SHOULD COME HERE

    console.log('eventDateControl :  '+eventDateControl);
    }
```

Comment: how can the input box change the value when it's marked `readonly`?

Comment: i am changing it using $scope.eventDateControl.It cannot be changed from the web page

Comment: can you put a watch and see if its being triggered? I'd suggest removing readonly and adding a class instead

Comment: right, because it's read only.

Comment: actually its a datepicker.when i select a new date, it comes into the input field but when i try to access it,it gives me the previous value.I can change the date using datepicker as well as $scope.ModelName

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a change function for `datetimepickerpicker` and then apply the scope into it.

And use jquery plugin through directive to get better binding, In below directive i added change function & after changing we need to run digest cycle manually to update scope values.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('dateTimePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        reuqire: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                // language: 'fr',
                weekStart: 1,
                todayBtn: 1,
                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 2,
                forceParse: 0,
                showMeridian: 1,
                onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue($input.val());
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="currentDate" date-time-picker class="form-control" size="16" 
type="text" value="" ng-model="eventDateControl"/>
```

Comment: which goes back to, why make a control `readonly` and then use a directive to get outside angular and capture the change to the element from jquery?  Obviously the element is meant to be changed......

Comment: unless I'm totally off my rocker, if `readonly` was taken off the input, the value would be updated automatically through the two way binding of `ng-model`  in your answer, you didn't include the `readonly` attribute either.

Comment: @Vallabh Lakade does it helped you?